# USB device not detected

Tags: usb, automount, devices, usb-drive

I have an audio recorder plugged to the laptop via USB. However, it is not correctly mounted by Ubuntu.
I haven't plugged it since some weeks, but I'm sure that the last time it was correctly automounted.
Also, other USB devices works pretty well.

What could the problem be?

### Potentially usefuls outputs

Don't know if it could be of help, but this is the output I have when the USB device is plugged in. It seems it doesn't appear anywhere.

```
$>lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:58bf Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5136:4678  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

-

```
$>lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2                 8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3                 8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4                 8:4    0  69,5G  0 part 
├─sda5                 8:5    0  97,7G  0 part /media/FastFiles
├─sda6                 8:6    0   7,8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda7                 8:7    0  48,8G  0 part /
└─sda8                 8:8    0  14,2G  0 part /home
sdb                    8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                 8:17   0 931,5G  0 part /media/Data
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0                  7:0    0    15G  0 loop 
└─truecrypt12 (dm-0) 252:0    0    15G  0 dm   /media/truecrypt12
```

As requested in a comment, I've unplugged the device, then runned `sudo dmesg -c`. [This](http://pastebin.com/0NqcfPDf) is the output.
Then, I've tried to plug the device again and run the same command; however, I got no result.

Comment: do this: unplug the device,  sudo dmesg -c then plug in the device, then dmesg. post results

Comment: @j0h edited my answer

Comment: I did not want to see the output of dmesg -c  that was to clear the dmesg buffer and only output what happens when the device gets plugged in.

Comment: @j0h however, there is no output at all when I plug-in the device again. In the first output though you can see a lot of lines that seems related to the problem.

Comment: Any how, some 8gb device was unproperly removed, and is marked with a dirty flag.  dmesg recommends you run fsck. is your audio device 8GB?

Comment: @j0h yes, this is my device. The problem is that I don't know its path; I mean, I have no `/dev/sdc1` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22810/discussion-between-j0h-and-tigerjack89).